# Trying to implement reCAPTCHA into my Contact form w/ Formspree

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I followed a tutorial online that showed how to add reCAPTCHA to a form in HTML, while also using an if/then script in PHP that displays a message if the captcha fails. I have everything working for the most part, but I'm trying to figure out how to submit the contact form through Formspree's redirect. When the user verifies the captcha and clicks the submit button, they are redirected to the test page, but I can't figure out how to send the form data. I'd imagine it'd have to be done in PHP, referencing the form's fields using variables, but I'm not too great at PHP myself.

Here's my HTML form:

```
<div id="form">
    <form method="post" action="http://formspree.io/MY@EMAIL.COM">
        <?php if(isset($_GET['CaptchaFail'])){ ?>
        <div class="row 50%">
            Captcha failed. Please try again.
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="12u"><textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6"></textarea></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <ul class="actions">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="--- my Google reCAPTCHA sitekey ---"></div>
                    <li">
                    <input name="ContactButton" type="submit" value="Send Message" id="ContactButton"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here's the PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['ContactButton'])){
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $privatekey = "--- my Google reCAPTCHA secret key ---";

        $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $data = json_decode($response);

        if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true){
            header('Location: submit.html');
        }else{
            header('Location: index.php?CaptchaFail=True#form');
        }
    }
?>
```

I know the action needs to be in the same section as the redirect to 'submit.html' takes place, but I wouldn't know what to add there that would submit the form. I had to remove the form action in order for the redirect to 'submit.html' to function. Otherwise, the submit button submits the form through Formspree regardless of whether the captcha is checked or not.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: TL;DR: You can't. The CAPTCHA handling would need to happen on Formspree's end, and they don't seem to support that.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help + link to the duplicate question.